# NIntegrate with units: unable to determine the units of quanitites that appear in the input

Tags: numerical-integration, units

I want to integrate Planck's law of radiation in a certain wavelength intervall with units.

I define some constants:

```
h = Quantity["PlanckConstant"];
c = Quantity["SpeedOfLight"];
kb = Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"];
```

and the function

```
Iplanck[\[Lambda]_, T_] := (2 \[Pi] h c^2)/\[Lambda]^5*1/(Exp[(h c)/(\[Lambda] kb T)] - 1);
```

When I try to integrate

```
NIntegrate[Iplanck[\[Lambda], Quantity[300, "kelvins"]], {\[Lambda], Quantity[632.75, "nm"], Quantity[632.85, "nm"]}]
```

or

```
NIntegrate[Iplanck[\[Lambda], T], {\[Lambda], Quantity[632.75, "nm"], Quantity[632.85, "nm"]}]
```

I get the error

```
NIntegrate::units: NIntegrate was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input. >>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nm may be ambiguous,  as in nautical miles or nano meter?

Comment: It's nano meters. When using Quanity["nm"] Mathematica interprets it correctly and changing to Quanity["nanometers"] doesn't work with NIntegrate either.

Comment: Right, nautical miles are either NM or nmi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put everything into SI units. Also, Mma appears to want "Kelvins" rather than "kelvins".

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
h = UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"]];

c = UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]];

kb = UnitConvert[Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]];

Iplanck[lambda_, T_] := Module[
  {lambdaSI = UnitConvert[lambda],
   TSI = UnitConvert[T]},
  (2 Pi h c^2)/lambdaSI^5*1/(Exp[(h c)/(lambdaSI kb TSI)] - 1)]

NIntegrate[
  Iplanck[\[Lambda], Quantity[300, "Kelvins"]], {\[Lambda], 
   Quantity[632.75, "nm"], 
   Quantity[632.85, "nm"]}] // Quiet
```

> Quantity[4.48782*10^-28, ("Kilograms")/("Seconds")^3]

Comment: That works! Do you know what the error Quantity::unkunit: "Unable to interpret unit specification {\!\(\"Kilograms\", \"Nanometers\", \"Seconds\"\)}." means?

Comment: Don't know why the error messages are generated; however, it appears that Mma is able to power through so I used `Quiet`. I edited out the redundant calls to `UnitConvert` in the integral bounds since that is handled by `Iplanck`.

Comment: @BobHanlon, is there a way to list `all` supported units? I think reference only lists a few examples.

Comment: @alancalvitti - I generally query WolframAlpha to get units, e.g., `WolframAlpha["SI unit for speed"]`.